# bing map CredentialsExpired

Tags: authentication, maps, bing-maps, credentials, bing

After about 20 minutes of inactivity, I cannot show a route in my Bing Map.
It seems that there is a problem with:

```
routeLoadModule=function routeLoadModule(){
        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', function() {
                //Create an instance of the directions manager.
                directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);
        directionsManager.setRenderOptions({
                itineraryContainer: '#directionsItinerary'
                });
        //Specify the where to display the input panel
                directionsManager.showInputPanel('directionsPanel');
        });
```

I get an error message from the browser:

```
Microsoft.Maps.NetworkCallbacks.f7628e ({"authenticationResultCode": "CredentialsExpired", "brandLogoUri": "http:\/\/dev.virtualearth.net\/Branding… “
```

I tried unsuccessfully to make a listener on "authenticationResultCode ":" CredentialsExpired" which trigger to refresh credentials.

I will be grateful for your help in solving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Bing Maps Web SDK creates a session key when it is loaded. All service requests made to Bing Maps are made using this session key and marks those requests as non-billable. This session key expires after about 20 minutes (most likely to prevent abuse of the non-billable usage). I believe the only way to recover when the key expires is to reload the map script and map (either dispose/reload within your app, or refresh the page).

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thank you for the information.